# use regex to remove external script tag

Tags: javascript, regex

I tried to remove the external script tag from a string using a regular expression.

```
var data = "<p>Valid paragraph.</p><p>Another valid paragraph.</p><script>alert123</script><script type='text/javascript' src='123'>Dangerous scripting!!!</script><script type='text/javascript' src='123'/><p>Last final paragraph.</p>";

data.replace(/<script[^>]\(\src=\)*>(?:(?!<\/script>)[^])*<\/script>/g, "")
```

output should be

```
"<p>Valid paragraph.</p><p>Another valid paragraph.</p><script>alert123</script><p>Last final paragraph.</p>";
```

but it not validating.
how to fix this issue?

Comment: Regex is not the right tool to do such stuff. Use some xml parser to modify the XML DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here I tested a regex and I think it is what you're looking for:

```regex
(<script[^>].*<\/script>)|(<script[^>].*\/\s?>)
```

https://regexr.com/5n377 see the effect!

### EDIT

```regex
(<script[^>].*?<\/script>)|(<script[^>].*\/\s?>)
            ^^^ here Edited
```

Comment: I fixed the issue. now it works fine @PatrickParker https://regexr.com/5n3ci

Comment: ok you fixed one problem with the reluctant qualifier. the other side of the regex still has the same problem with greedy qualifier. and there are countless ways it can fail. regex is the wrong approach here.